# Making an array of tokens from string with strtok, malloc, and realloc

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc, strtok

There are some topics that partially overlap with this but I am still seeking an answer.

The tokenizing part is working fine but the dynamic memory allocation seems not to be, based on a segfault when the print loop is uncommented.

The free() is just to check whether free() works, not to be part of the finished function, and it is returning NULL until it can return something sensible.

sep is usually a space. Any \n on the end of line is taken care of before it gets here.

```
char ** chunkify(char *line, char *sep)
{
   printf("%s\n", line);

   char **array = malloc(sizeof(char *));        
   int token_count = 0;
   char *token = NULL;   
   token = strtok(line, sep);

   while( token != NULL )
   {              
      printf("\t%s\n", token);
      array = realloc(array,(token_count + 1) * sizeof(char *));      
      array[token_count] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
      strcpy(array[token_count],token);
      token = strtok(NULL, sep);
      token_count++;
   }  

   /*
   int j;
   for ( j=0 ; *(array+j) ; ++j)
   {
      printf("\t%s\n", *(array+j));
      free(*(array+j)); // just to see if it frees cleanly
   }
   free(array);
   */

   return NULL; // will return array when it's fixed
}
```

Comment: `malloc/strcpy` can be replaced by `strdup`.

Comment: `*(array+j)` : The area of `NULL` as sentinel is not secured and stored. and Add the caller's code.

Comment: @EugeneSh., `strdup` is not in standard C (but widely available), so if this is some sort of exercise, this could be problematic.

Comment: The print loop attempts to iterate until it meets a NULL pointer, but you do not ensure that there is a NULL pointer at the end of the list.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer Hm.you are right, wasn't aware it is not standard.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer-- [it _is_ POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html), so that's something....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should append the array of pointers with a null pointer. Otherwise it is unknown how many elements the array contains.

If to use your approach that is not smart enough because it does not report an allocation error then the function can look as it is shown in this demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char ** chunkify( char *line, const char *sep )
{
    char **array = malloc( sizeof( char * ) );

    if ( array )
    {
        size_t n = 1;

        char *token = strtok( line, sep );

        while ( token )
        {
            char **tmp = realloc( array, ( n + 1 ) * sizeof( char * ) );

            if ( tmp == NULL ) break;

            array = tmp;
            ++n;

            array[ n - 2 ] = malloc( strlen( token ) + 1 );
            if ( array[ n - 2 ] != NULL ) strcpy( array[ n - 2 ], token );

            token = strtok( NULL, sep );
        }

        array[ n - 1 ] = NULL;
    }

    return array;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "Hello World";
    char **array = chunkify( s, " " );

    if ( array != NULL )
    {
        for ( char **p = array; *p; ++p ) puts( *p );

        for ( char **p = array; *p; ++p ) free( *p );
        free( array );
    }       

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello
World
```

Comment: Because I am a nube I can't upvote comments or answers, so thank you for the tip about ending the array with a NULL pointer. That proved very useful. Along the way I also learned not to nest calls to strtok. Lost a day or two on that.

Comment: @phlatphish You may select the best answer that is in this case a single answer.:)